# Ng-Controller Not Passing Data

Tags: angularjs

I'm an angular newbie and am working on a small project and have come across a weird problem with ng-controller. When I use the controller within my partial view, the customer's name does not get passed into the value property.

However, if I inject the customersFactory (which has a function that makes an http request to the database to get all customers) into the ordersController, everything works fine.

My routeProvider code:

```
        myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'ordersController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/orders.html'
        })
        .when('/customers', {
            controller: 'customersController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/customers.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
    });

    myApp.factory('ordersFactory', function($http) {
        var orders = [];

        var factory = {};

        factory.getOrders = function(callback) {
            $http.get('/orders').success(function(data) {
                orders = data;
                callback(orders);
            })
        }

        factory.addOrder = function(data) {
            return $http.post('/add/order', data);
        }

        factory.deleteOrder = function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/delete/order/' + id);
        }

        return factory;
    });

    myApp.factory('customersFactory', function($http) {
        var customers = [];

        var factory = {};

        factory.getCustomers = function(callback) {
            $http.get('/customers').success(function(data) {
                customers = data;
                callback(customers);
            })
        }

        factory.addCustomer = function(data) {
            return $http.post('/add/customer', data);
        }

        factory.removeCustomer = function(customer_id) {
            return $http.delete('/delete/customer/' + customer_id);
        }

        return factory;
    });

    myApp.controller('ordersController', function($scope, ordersFactory) {

        var getOrders = function() {
            ordersFactory.getOrders(function(data) {
                $scope.orders = data;
            });
        }

        getOrders();

        $scope.addOrder = function() {
            console.log($scope.order);
            ordersFactory.addOrder($scope.order);
            $scope.order = {};
            getOrders();
        }

        $scope.deleteOrder = function(id) {
            ordersFactory.deleteOrder(id);
            getOrders();
        }

    });

    myApp.controller('customersController', function($scope, customersFactory) {

        var getCustomers = function() {
            customersFactory.getCustomers(function(data) {
                $scope.customers = data;
            })
        }

        getCustomers();

        $scope.addCustomer = function() {
            customersFactory.addCustomer($scope.customer);
            $scope.customer = {};
            getCustomers();
        }

        $scope.removeCustomer = function(customer_id) {
            customersFactory.removeCustomer(customer_id);
            getCustomers();
        }
    });
```

Here's the orders.html partial page.

```
<h2>Add New Order</h2>
<form>
<label for="name">Customer</label>
<select name="name" ng-model="order.name" ng-controller="customersController">
    <option ng-repeat="customer in customers" value="{{customer.name}}">{{ customer.name }}</option>
</select>
<label for="quantity">Order</label>
<select name="quantity" ng-model="order.quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="product" ng-model="order.product">
    <option value="Nike Shoes">Nike Shoes</option>
    <option value="Black Belts">Black Belts</option>
    <option value="Ice Creams">Ice Creams</option>
    <option value="Candies">Candies</option>
    <option value="Waffles">Waffles</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Order" ng-click="addOrder()">
</form>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Customer Name</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <td>{{ order.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.product }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.date }}</td>
        <td><a href="#/" ng-click="deleteOrder(order._id)">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone please explain why this is the case? My initial guess is that it has something to do with not explicitly assigning $scope.customers but I am under the impression that as soon as ng-controller is detected, it executes all of the "self-executing functions" which would then assign the data to $scope.customers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-model` in place of value and instead of `<option>` tag use ng-options in select tag it is fast as compare the `<option>` tag

```
<select name="name" ng-model="order.name" ng-controller="ordersController" ng-options="customer as customer in customers" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-model="customer.name"` instead of `value="{{customer.name}}"`

Comment: EDIT: Added controllers and factories to original post.

Comment: Updated my answer, btw.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Sorry that I didn't upload all of my code from the get go. I am using routeProvider to determine which controller to use with each respective template which is where my ordersController is being called. I used ng-controller="customersController" to get only the customer's name so that I can display it in the drop down menu.

Comment: You're too fast at replying :P. Just edited what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ngOptions directive instead. The documentation can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<select name="name" ng-model="order.name" ng-options="customer as customer.name for customer in customers track by customer.name" ng-controller="ordersController">
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the information on ng-options. This is my first time hearing about it. I used your answer and Vipin's answer but unfortunately, the customer's name does not show up in the table (but shows up in the drop down menu even after I deleted all of the option tags).

Comment: Whoops! That's because it's assigning the entire customer to order.name instead of just customer.name, you can change the ng-options to ng-options="customer.name for customer in customers track by customer.name" and it should just assign customer.name to order.name.

Comment: Hey Nick, so close!  Instead of the name, it shows the customer's ObjectId. When I look at the customer's database, the names are correct. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your feedback. I think I've figured out the root of my issue(s).

1. I am not using ng-options to iterate over an array full of objects.
2. I am calling the ordersController in the routeProvider but am overriding it with customersController which is causing ng-model="order.name" to not be passed into the scope.

Any pointers on what I can do to fix #2? Does "ng-controller='customersController' have to come before the  tag in order for "ng-options" to display the options correctly?

Comment: You should not use answers to ask for clarification. Edit the question instead and add a note that you still need #2 answered.